# Python Fabric Sudo Then Connect using Sudo Privilege

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, ssh, sudo, fabric

first time question here, apologies if I cannot format this properly.

I am using Python 3.9.13 with Fabric 3.2.2 to do ssh to 3 ubuntu server (server1, server2 and server3) and do some commands as below for simulation on my work related request.

Steps are :

1. Connect normally to server1, do some command.
2. Jump to server2 from server1, do some command.
3. Use sudo to jump to server3 from server2 and do some command (server2 user can only ssh if root/sudo privilege).

Manually in terminal is as below, connecting here starts from server1:

```
su user1 
user1@596dccdb1bf3:/$ ssh usertest@172.17.0.3 
usertest@172.17.0.3s password:  
Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 x86_64)

Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com 
Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com 
Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

This system has been minimized by removing packages and content that are not required on a system that users do not log into.

To restore this content, you can run the 'unminimize' command. Last login: Thu Nov  9 03:04:40 2023 from 172.17.0.2

usertest@f62ea909f24e:~$ whoami 
usertest 
usertest@f62ea909f24e:~$ ssh user3@172.17.0.4
> -bash: /usr/bin/ssh: Permission denied 
usertest@f62ea909f24e:~$ sudo -i 
root@f62ea909f24e:~# ssh user3@172.17.0.4 
user3@172.17.0.4s password:  
Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 x86_64)

Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com 
Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com 
Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

This system has been minimized by removing packages and content that are not required on a system that users do not log into.

To restore this content, you can run the 'unminimize' command. Last login: Wed Nov  8 03:24:46 2023 from 172.17.0.3 
user3@0044b76bfff8:~$ whoami 
user3 
user3@0044b76bfff8:~$
```

As with python fabric, I am using below code for sample purposes :

```
from fabric import Connection, Config

server1_ip = 'localhost' 
server1_port = 2200 
server1_user = 'user1' 
server1_pass = '123456'

server2_ip = '172.17.0.3' 
server2_port = 22 
server2_user = 'usertest' 
server2_pass = '123456' 
server2_sudopass = '123456'

server3_ip = '172.17.0.4' 
server3_port = 22 
server3_user = 'user3' 
server3_pass = '123456' 
server3_sudopass = '123456'

#connect to server1 
conn1 = Connection(host=server1_ip, user=server1_user, port=server1_port, connect_kwargs={"password": server1_pass}) 
print(conn1.run('whoami', hide=True)) 
print("Connected to server1")

#jump to server2 from server1 
conn2 = Connection(host=server2_ip, user=server2_user, port=server2_port, connect_kwargs={"password": server2_pass}, gateway=Connection(host=server1_ip,user=server1_user, port=server1_port, connect_kwargs={"password": server1_pass}))    
print(conn2.run('whoami', hide=True)) 
print("Connected to server2")

#jump to server3 from server2, using sudo privilege on server2 
config = Config(overrides={'sudo': {'password': server2_sudopass}}) 
conn3 = Connection(host=server3_ip, user=server3_user, port=server3_port, connect_kwargs={"password": server3_pass},  gateway=Connection(host=server2_ip,user=server2_user, port=server2_port, connect_kwargs={"password": server2_pass}), config=config)

print(conn3.run('whoami', hide=True)) 
print("Connected to server3")

#disconnect from all 
conn3.close() 
conn2.close() 
conn1.close()
```

Its running Ok from server1 to server2, but from server2 to server3, it cannot connect with below error :

```
Command exited with status 0. stdout === 
user1

(no stderr) 
Connected to server1 
Command exited with status 0. stdout === 
usertest

(no stderr) 
Connected to server2 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "d:\jobs\TEF-bash-executor\loopssh_test.py", line 39, in <module> print(conn3.run('whoami', hide=True)) 
File "d:\jobs\TEF-bash-executor\.venv\lib\site-packages\decorator.py", line 232, in fun return caller(func, *(extras + args), **kw) 
File "d:\jobs\TEF-bash-executor\.venv\lib\site-packages\fabric\connection.py", line 22, in opens self.open() 
File "d:\jobs\TEF-bash-executor\.venv\lib\site-packages\fabric\connection.py", line 638, in open kwargs["sock"] = self.open_gateway() 
File "d:\jobs\TEF-bash-executor\.venv\lib\site-packages\fabric\connection.py", line 691, in open_gateway self.gateway.open() 
File "d:\jobs\TEF-bash-executor\.venv\lib\site-packages\fabric\connection.py", line 665, in open result = self.client.connect(**kwargs) 
File "d:\jobs\TEF-bash-executor\.venv\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 358, in connect retry_on_signal(lambda: sock.connect(addr)) 
File "d:\jobs\TEF-bash-executor\.venv\lib\site-packages\paramiko\util.py", line 279, in retry_on_signal return function() 
File "d:\jobs\TEF-bash-executor\.venv\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 358, in <lambda> retry_on_signal(lambda: sock.connect(addr)) 
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Please note, i'm not allowed to make any changes to the network/ubuntu settings, since this is a task to automate connecting so several ssh and do multiple commands, so can only do in Python.

Very much appreciate help should there is anyone with expertise in Fabric, since I am not that experienced and my Linux knowledge is not that much.

Thanks!